# Sticky nav assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I've been trying to make a sticky nav with the source code down bellow, but just simply cant find anything or make anything work.

The code has the two nav bars TOP & MID that i'd hope someone could help me create the TOPnav go behind the MIDnav at a certain point to create that sticky like effect.

I have no JS linked cause i hope someone could give me a rough idea of what to do.

thank you :).

PS: if anything in my code seem  odd/weird or perhaps not needed feel free to point it out as i hope to improve it.

```css
html{

overflow-x: hidden;
height: 2000px;


background: white;
}


.TOPNAV {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -720px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-top: 70px solid #AC3838;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
.TOPNAV a {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 0 #000, 2px 4px 10px black;
}
.TOPNAV li {
  float: left;
  width: 15vw;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.MIDNAV {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 730px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #575194;
  z-index: 10;
}
.MIDNAV a {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 0 #000, 2px 4px 10px black;
}
.MIDNAV li {
  float: left;
  width: 15vw;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<html>


<head>

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".//CSS\SCRAP_CSS.css">


  <script src="JS/jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/SCRAP.js"></script>



  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>






  <div class="TOPNAV">



    <li><a href="Page2.html">Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">Index</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">About</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">List</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">Login</a> 
    </li>


  </div>




  <div class="MIDNAV">


    <li><a href="Page2.html">Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">Index</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">About</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">List</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Page2.html">Login</a> 
    </li>


  </div>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple sticky nav with pure Javascript, html and css then you can use this snippet. I got it [from the 30day Javascript tutorial](http://javascript30.com) which I highly recommend and I added some comments.
Credits to [Wes Bos](http://wesbos.com/).

```js
   // grab the element that contains the navigation we want to create a sticky effect for
const nav = document.querySelector("#main");

// create a variable that stores the height of the space between the top of the parent node (in this case our body element) of our nav and the top of our nav
let topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;

// create our function that should run everytime the user scrolls
function fixNav() {
  // if the user scrolls further down than the height of our variable add the class fixed-nav and add a padding
  if( window.scrollY >= topOfNav ) {
    // the padding is added because the element is removed from the document flow due to position: fixed
    document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
    // position: add css class fixed-nav
    document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav'); 
    } else {
    // remove the class and padding when the user scrolls above our nav again
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    document.body.classList.remove('fixed-nav');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

body {
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
  }

.upper-space {
  display: block; 
  background: red;
  height:200px
  }

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  height: 100px;
  }

ul.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  }

.navigation li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  }

.fixed-nav #main {
  position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div class="upper-space">
  </div>
  
  <nav id="main">
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li>menu item 1</li>
      <li>menu item 2</li>
      <li>menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  Suscipit, libero, aperiam est sequi aspernatur malesuada ratione, quaerat ipsa posuere nisl perferendis laboris facilisis voluptas conubia sodales, dolorem? Malesuada purus, dolorem torquent distinctio, animi qui rerum, culpa. Mattis accumsan doloribus pellentesque eveniet. Porro sequi omnis soluta inceptos, dicta curae hac adipiscing anim adipiscing ante. Luctus hymenaeos pharetra, facilisi explicabo.

Laboris justo tincidunt illo incididunt erat netus quisquam doloremque eos habitasse sequi! Rerum primis, sodales! Totam, feugiat mattis est atque! Eiusmod curabitur deserunt earum quis, libero euismod reiciendis quae et, perspiciatis donec voluptates, consequuntur, vel purus! Voluptate platea doloribus? Blanditiis aptent litora excepteur vulputate! Cursus. Felis nostrum mattis, nisi, adipiscing.
  
</body>
```